# Smallest element array higher than average

Tags: java, arrays

i have a two dimensional array, i count average of elements. I'm looking for smallest number in array, higher than counted average

```
int tmp, tmp1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (averageElements < array[i][j]) {
                tmp = array[i][j];
                if (tmp > tmp1) {
                    tmp1 = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 System.out.println("Smallest element array higher than average " + tmp1);
```

for example:

1 1 2 1

1 1 1 5

1 1 1 9

1 1 3 1

average elements 2.16

higher than average: 3, 5, 9

smallest number in numbers higher than average -> 3

Comment: i don't understand the question... are you trying to find the average value in the array or are you trying to find the smallest number in the array?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking and what are you having problems with.

Comment: The condition must be (averageElements < array[i][j]) to get an element higher than the average ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (averageElements > array[i][j])` means that you're only looking at values *less* than the average, exactly opposite of what you want.

`tmp1 = 0` and `if (array[i][j] > tmp1)` means that you are looking for the *largest* value above zero, also exactly opposite of what you want. And it wouldn't work if all values were negative.

Instead, try this:

```
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        int value = array[i][j];
        if (averageElements < value && value < minValue) {
            minValue = value;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Smallest element array higher than average " + minValue);
```